# How to have two labels side by side, one that can grow, and one cannot?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have two labels side by side. And I have two constraints set. Label-A starts at the leading edge of the view. Label-B starts 10px from trailing edge of Label-1. There are no width constraints.

Label-A's text length varies; Label-B's text is fixed (6 chars long). This works fine until length of Label-A goes over a certain point. Then Label-B goes off screen.

Before I assign the text value to Label-A, I want to truncate Label-A text with '...' if it will push Label-B beyond the trailing edge of the view. Any idea how to figure out if I should truncate Label-A's text and by how much? This has to work in both portrait and landscape modes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the `horizontal content hugging priority` and `horizontal content compression resistance priority` of `Label-B` higher than `Label-A`. And also add trailing of `Label-B` to superview.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 9):

Set **Content Compression Resistance Priority** for one of both label, according to your requirement.

Look at these snapshots:

Two labels with default `content compression resistance priority`.

[image]

I changed `content compression resistance priority` for label `blablabla blablabla`, from `750` to `749`.

Result is:

[image]

For more details see Apple document: [Setting Content-Hugging and Compression-Resistance Priorities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1)

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that your labels have constraints for leading and trailing.

Your views layout should like this:

`|-8-[Label-A]-10-[Label-B]-8-|`

After that set the `horizontal content hugging priority` and the `horizontal compression resistance` of `Label-B` higher than `Label-A`.